# How to find the crash position from customer's ipad log?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, crash

I know a crash in my app form customer's iPad log, the exception is :-`[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`, but I cannot position this crash in code and I cannot reproduce it because I know so litte about this crash. I need help, thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log. Search here, Google, or the Apple iOS docs for many discussions about how to do that.

Comment: our game has been released a few weeks ago. the crash info is from customer, my superior said no more info but this line:" 10/26/12 06:07:17 AM PDT "," 1 "," NSRangeException: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array "," Crash! "," 1.1.0 "," Uncaught ","  "," iPad "
what should I do?

Comment: You don't have a full crash log? If all you have is that one message then there is nothing you can do. You need the full crash log.

Comment: ask your client to send the crash log.If not possible, ask him to tell the steps he took for the crash to occur.It may help you exactly which class or method may be the reason for the crash.

Comment: luckily, I reproduced another crash, when I set a cclayer's isTouchEnabled to false and then show an alertview in its tocuhended method, it cause a crash, thanks for your answers.